# How to pass a function as an argument

Tags: python

I would like to find an approximate value for the number `pi = 3.14..` by using the Newton method. In order to use it also for some other purpose and thus other function than `sin(x)`, the aim is to implement a generic function that will be passed over as an argument. I have an issue in passing a function as an argument into an other function. I also tried `lambda` in different variations. The code I am showing below produces the error message: `IndexError: list index out of range`. I will appreciate your help in solving this issue and eventually make any suggestion in the code which may not be correct. Thanks.

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
import math

x = Symbol('x')
# find the derivative of f
def deriv(f,x):
    h = 1e-5 
    return (lambda x: (f(x+h)-f(x))/h)

def newton(x0,f,err):
    A = [x0]
    n = 1
    while abs(A[n]-A[n-1])<=err:
        if n == 1:
            y = lambda x0: (math.f(x0))
            b = x0-y(x0)/(deriv(y,x0))
            A.append(b)
            n += 1             
        else:
            k = len(A)
            xk = A[k]
            y = lambda xk: (math.f(xk))
            b = newton(A[k],y,err)-y(newton(A[k],y,err))/deriv(y,k)
            A.append(b)
            n += 1
    return A, A[-1]
print(newton(3,math.sin(3),0.000001))
```

Comment: `(math.f(xk))` - try removing the outer parenthesis.

Comment: you can pass the function as an parameter to other function just like you do with other functions. ```func_2(another_func)```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to trace through the logic of the code. We set `A = [x0]` and `n = 1`, and then immediately we try to check whether `abs(A[n]-A[n-1])`. Think carefully about this. How many elements do you think are in `A` at this point? Therefore, what values can be used to index into `A`? Is `n` one of those values? is `n-1` one of those values? Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and try to trace through the logic of your code first before posting.

Comment: BTW, with how you initialize `y`, you're not passing the function `math.f` as input.

Comment: As an aside, nothing in this code actually uses the global `x = Symbol('x')`, and `math.f` makes no sense - there is no function named `f` in the standard library `math` module. It's not clear how you intend for Sympy to help out with the problem, either, but perhaps it [would be better](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to [look for a tutorial](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sympy+newton%27s+method).

Comment: A = [x0] means it has only one element, with index 0. But then you do A[n] where starts in 1, so A[1] doesn't exist at that point.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: your problem is `abs(A[n]-A[n-1])`. You should rather start with `n= 0` and run code for `if n == 1:` before `while`-loop

Comment: there are other problems. You send `f` to function but later you use `math.f` which doesn't exists. You assign value to `x0` and later you use the same variable in `lambda x0: ...` which can make problem. And the same is with `xk` and `lamda xk: ...` - maybe it should be different varlable. OR you could use directly `f` instead of `y`. And if `math.sin(3)` gives value but you assign it to variable `f` and it suggest that you want to use it as function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you use `sympy` because I made it without `Symbol`

At the beginning you have to calculate second value and append it to list `A` and later you can calculate `abs(A[n]-A[n-1])` (or the same without `n`: `abs(A[-1] - A[-2])`) because it needs two values from this list.

Other problem is that it has to check `>` instead of `<=`.

If you want to send function `sin(x)` then you have to use `math.sin` without `()` and arguments.

If you want to send function `sin(3*x)` then you would have to use `lambda x: math.sin(3*x)`

```
import math

def deriv(f, x, h=1e-5):
    return (f(x+h) - f(x)) / h

def newton(x0, f, err):
    A = [x0]

    x = A[-1]                     # get last value
    b = x - (f(x) / deriv(f, x))  # calculate new value
    A.append(b)                   # add to list

    while abs(A[-1] - A[-2]) > err:   # it has to be `>` instead of `<=`
        
        x = A[-1]                     # get last value
        b = x - (f(x) / deriv(f, x))  # calculate new value
        A.append(b)                   # add to list
        
    return A, A[-1]

# sin(x)
print(newton(3, math.sin, 0.000001))  # it needs function's name without `()`

# sin(3*x)
print(newton(3, lambda x:math.sin(3*x), 0.000001))

# sin(3*x)  # the same without `lambda`
def function(x):
    return math.sin(3*x)

print(newton(3, function, 0.000001))
```

Result:

```
([3, 3.1425464414785056, 3.1415926532960112, 3.141592653589793], 3.141592653589793)
([3, 3.150770863559604, 3.1415903295877707, 3.1415926535897936, 3.141592653589793], 3.141592653589793)
```

---

**EDIT:**

You may write loop in newton in different way and it will need `<=`

```
def newton(x0, f, err):
    A = [x0]

    while True:
        
        x = A[-1]                     # get last value
        b = x - (f(x) / deriv(f, x))  # calculate new value
        A.append(b)                   # add to list
        
        if abs(A[-1] - A[-2]) <= err: 
            break
        
    return A, A[-1]
```